# Android custom view drawing twice

Tags: android

In my activity `A`, this view called twice, but in my activity `B`, there is no problem.

Activity `A` is very simple layout with a few linearLayout. I'm about to go crazy, what can be the problem?

Here is I have my `AdBannerView`:

```
public class AdBannerView extends LinearLayout {

    public ImageView adIcon, adInstall;
    public TextView_ adTitle, adDesc;
    public ProgressBar adProgress;
    RelativeLayout adWrapperLay;
    private boolean impSent, adLoaded = false;

    public AdBannerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AdBannerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public AdBannerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View wrapper = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_ad_banner, this, true);

        adIcon = (ImageView) wrapper.findViewById(R.id.adIcon);
        adInstall = (ImageView) wrapper.findViewById(R.id.adInstall);
        adTitle = (TextView_) wrapper.findViewById(R.id.adTitle);
        adDesc = (TextView_) wrapper.findViewById(R.id.adDesc);
        adProgress = (ProgressBar) wrapper.findViewById(R.id.adProgress);
        adWrapperLay = (RelativeLayout) wrapper.findViewById(R.id.adWrapperLay);

        Log.d("AdBannerView", "before loadAd()");

        if(NativeAdManager.getInstance().isAdEnabled)
            loadAd();
    }

    public void loadAd(){

        if(adLoaded)
            return;

        adLoaded = true;

        Log.d("AdBannerView", "loadAd() request");

        NativeAdManager.getInstance().getAd(getContext(), new NativeAdManager.AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void adLoaded(final NativeAdResponse.Ads[] ads) {

                /* load img */
                Picasso
                        .with(getContext())
                        .load(ads[0].adIc)
                        .into(adIcon);

                /* load title */
                adTitle.setText(""+ads[0].adTit);
                adDesc.setText(""+ads[0].adDesc);

                /* click listener */
                adInstall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        App app = (App) getContext().getApplicationContext();
                        app.getUiController().loadUrlWithoutAdBlocker(ads[0].adClk);

                    }
                });

                /* show this layout */
                showAd(ads[0].adBeacons);

                Log.d("AdBannerView", "loaded with size = " + ads.length);

            }
        });
    }

    private void showAd(final NativeAdResponse.adBeacons[] adBeacons) {

        adProgress.setVisibility(GONE);
        adIcon.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

    }
}
```

I'm including to layout like this:

```
<.... AdBannerView match_parent etc  />
```

Logs that proves drawing twice:

```
10-29 20:28:19.219    6698-6698/pack D/AdBannerView﹕ before loadAd()
10-29 20:28:19.219    6698-6698/pack D/AdBannerView﹕ loadAd() request
10-29 20:28:19.295    6698-6698/pack D/AdBannerView﹕ before loadAd()
10-29 20:28:19.295    6698-6698/pack D/AdBannerView﹕ loadAd() request
10-29 20:28:19.636    6698-6698/pack D/AdBannerView﹕ loaded with size = 1
10-29 20:28:19.852    6698-6698/pack D/AdBannerView﹕ loaded with size = 1
```

Problematic activity A:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <package.AdManager.AdBannerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity A.java (`I deleted everything in layout and class except of AdBannerView but still same`):

package package.Activity;

```
public class NewsRead extends Base {

    ToolBarView toolBarView;
    RelativeLayout backgroundLayForMainBgColor;

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView_ titleText, contentText, sourceText;
    LinearLayout wrapperLay /* for homeViewRowBg */, relatedNewsLay;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutResourceId());

        /*
        this.toolBarView = (ToolBarView) findViewById(R.id.toolBarView);
        this.backgroundLayForMainBgColor = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.backgroundLayForMainBgColor);

        this.imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        this.titleText = (TextView_) findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        this.contentText = (TextView_) findViewById(R.id.contentText);
        this.sourceText = (TextView_) findViewById(R.id.sourceText);
        this.wrapperLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wrapperLay);

        changeTheme();

        toolBarView.hideDeleteButton().setToolBarClickListener(new ToolBarView.ToolBarClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void backButtonClick() {
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void deleteButtonClick() {

            }

        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if(intent == null)
            return;

        loadNewsDetail(intent);

        */

    }

    private void loadNewsDetail(Intent intent) {
        String neTi = intent.getStringExtra("neTi");
        String neCo = intent.getStringExtra("neCo");
        String neSi = intent.getStringExtra("neSi");
        String neIm = intent.getStringExtra("neIm");
        String neUr = intent.getStringExtra("neUr");

        /**/

        Picasso
              .with(this)
              .load(neIm)
               //.placeholder(R.drawable.icon_placeholder)
              .into(imageView);

        titleText.setText(neTi);
        contentText.setText(neCo);
        sourceText.setText("Source: "+ Html.fromHtml("<u>"+neSi+"</u>"));

    }

    private void changeTheme() {
        ThemeModel curTheme = ThemeController.getInstance().getCurrentTheme();

        if(curTheme.hasBgImage()) {
            backgroundLayForMainBgColor.setBackground(curTheme.mainBgDrawable);
        } else {
            backgroundLayForMainBgColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(ThemeController.getInstance().getCurrentTheme().mainBgColor));
        }

        wrapperLay.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(curTheme.homeViewRowBg));
    }

    protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
        return R.layout.activity_news_read;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSoftInputShown() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSoftInputHidden() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String getActivityName() {
        return "news_read";
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    }

}
```

Base:

```
public abstract class Base extends Activity {

    private boolean isKeyboardOpened;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(getLayoutResourceId());
        keyBoardListener();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TrackingController.onActivityOpen(getActivityName());
            }
        }, 50);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    protected abstract int getLayoutResourceId();

    public void Toast(String str) {
        Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void Log(String str) {
        Log.d("act_name:"+getActivityName(), str);
    }

    private void keyBoardListener(){
        final View activityRootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

            int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
            if (heightDiff > 100 ) { // 99% of the time the height diff will be due to a keyboard.

                if(isKeyboardOpened == false){
                    onSoftInputShown();
                }
                isKeyboardOpened = true;
            }else if(isKeyboardOpened == true){
                onSoftInputHidden();
                isKeyboardOpened = false;
            }
            }
        });
    }

    public String getString_(int resId){
        return getResources().getString(resId);
    }

    protected abstract void onSoftInputShown();
    protected abstract void onSoftInputHidden();

    protected abstract String getActivityName();

}
```

Comment: please put your activity where you call from or check if you had call from onResume() and another method

Comment: Yep there is no issue in the currently posted code i think

Comment: I updated with activity A files.

Comment: Maybe you can debug your activity to pinpoint where it does load exactly. Eg put breakpoint in on create and in all of your constructors of the custom ad control and see which line calls the constructors. In the meantime I'll run android studio to try to reproduce it.

Comment: I tried to debug with activity as you said but I couldn't find a problem. Thank you for helping this strange issue. I'm still trying to find bug.

Comment: Ok some questions because with more simplified version the control was created only once: 1. Is your activity on create fired more than once 2. Is it possible something in base activity to fire the add 3.Is it possible that you register the a listener more than 1 time somewhere 4. NativeAdManager.getInstance().getAd(getContext(), new NativeAdManager.AdListener() ... is it possible something happens here or at some other point using the NativeAdManager. 6. Is it possible for you to add some more logs at key places and show us extended loging :)

Comment: Simple answers: 1-Only once, 2-Nope, 3-, Nope, 4- Yeah!. Thanks so much, you found the bug! (I hope)........Ah,  I was using this view in another activity, I thought the listener fired twice but after removing from other activity, I'm still seeing same problem. But anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: If It's not it try the next step, and we can continue :)

Comment: This view certainly drawing twice because before the listenter, "before loadAd()" logs twice..

Comment: My idea was that maybe something in getAd might be happening, if you put a breakpoint on that exact row we can check what's happening. You will have logs executed 1 time at that point, and then if you press step over if you enter in the init for second time you will know that this causes the issue. If not we can eliminate this. Ah saw you found the cause maybe, so good luck on fixing it ;)

Comment: I tested again without extending my "Base" activity and it turned out that problem is in Base class.  I added it to bottom of question. Can you check it? I guess getViewTreeObserver() was causing.

Comment: Interestingly my two activities extending Base class but this one had error with it. I removed Base class in this problematic activity and now it renders that problamatic view once. Thanks for your great help.

Comment: I think I know what it is, just a second to test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your bug :) Hopefully

You have in your base a call to setContentView and then in your deriving class you have call to super create (which calls the setContentView [which creates the adElement]) but after that you call again setContentView(getLayoutResourceId()); (this time from your derived class which overrides the layout but even if it didn't it's calling actually the same content I imagine so that's why it looks normal :)

So the fix should be easy - remove the setContentView(getLayoutResourceId()) from your activity A because it's already called from the base activity

Comment: @Lazy I've edited a little the answer, if it doesn't work let me know

Comment: I thank you despite you made me think about my IQ level. Anyway, thanks for your great help, I am such a "blind".

Comment: No worries, my pleasure ;) and if I were to pretend I'm funny, this comment would be - "you're not "blind", just Lazy..." *not funny... :D